# Структура проекта (использование компараторов)

Tags: c#, чистый-код

У меня есть класс Client и класс Processing, который служит для обработки данных класса Client. Они находятся в разных файлах Client.cs и Processing.cs соответственно. Для клиента надо написать три сортировки по различным полям используя компараторы. Сами методы сортировки будут лежать в классе Processing.
Вопрос: компараторы лучше вынести в один файл или в разные или (другой вариант)?

Comment: Разницы 0, хоть 2 файла, хоть 10.

Comment: Компараторы лучше вынести в отдельные файлы в отдельной директории. Если их действительно много, возможно, имеет смысл создать для по отдельному SharedProject для каждого вида сортировки.